# Change the number of MSAA smaples

Tags: webgl

I can get the number of MSAA samples like this:

```
gl.getParameter(gl.SAMPLES);
```

Is it possible to change the number of samples, either in JavaScript or in browser settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sometimes change the MSAA sample count in Chrome.  Go to web page chrome://flags and look for "GPU rasterization MSAA sample count".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No

WebGL 1.0 does not allow changing the samples. To do that requires the ability to create multi-sampled renderbuffers which has not been exposed in WebGL 1.0

WebGL 2.0, whenever it ships, should allow creating your own multi-sample renderbuffers. It's not clear if it will allow setting the number of samples for the canvas itself though.